# sort graph edges in increasing order

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, graph, linked-list

I am representing graphs using the standard adjacency list representation where each node is going out as an linked list. You can read more about adjacency list [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/graph-and-its-representations/).

Lets say below is my graph:

```
         10
    0--------1
    |  \     |
   6|   5\   |15
    |      \ |
    2--------3
        4
```

Adjacency list would look like as :

```
[0,  1,  2,  3]
 |   |   |   |
 10  10  6   6
 |   |   |   |
[1] [0] [0] [2]
 |   |   |   |
 6   15  4   5
 |   |   |   |
[2] [3] [3] [0]
 |   |   |   |
 |   |   |   15
    NULL     |
            [1]
             |
             |
            NULL
```

Since the graph is undirected, edges should be added from source to destination and from destination to source as well along with the weight of the edges. This is how code representation would looks like in that case.

```
// Linked list representation
class Adj_Node {
  public:
    int data;
    int weight;
    Adj_Node* next;
};

// Adjacency list representation
class Adj_List {
  public:
    Adj_Node* head;
};

// Graph representation
class Graph {
  public:
    int vertices;
    Adj_List* source;
    Graph(int v) {
      vertices = v;
      source = new Adj_List[vertices];

      for (int i = 0; i < vertices; ++i) {
        source[i].head = NULL;
      }
    }
    void addEdge(int, int, int);
    void printGraph();
};

// Creates an linked list node
Adj_Node* createNode(int d) {
  Adj_Node* tmp = new Adj_Node;
  tmp->data   = d;
  tmp->weight = 0;
  tmp->next   = NULL;

  return tmp;
}

// Adds edge to both src and destination
void Graph::addEdge(int src, int dest, int weight) {
  Adj_Node* node = createNode(dest);
  node->next = source[src].head;
  source[src].head = node;
  node->weight = weight;

  node = createNode(src);
  node->next = source[dest].head;
  source[dest].head = node;
  node->weight = weight;
}

void Graph::printGraph() {
  for(int i = 0; i < vertices; ++i) {
  Adj_Node* n = source[i].head;
  std::cout << i << " = ";
  while(n != NULL) {
    std::cout << n->data << " " << n->weight << ", ";
    n = n->next;
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

So, having said all of the above, I have above depiction linked list representation with me where each weighted edge of the graph is depicted as an node in an linked list.
Question is : What are the ways you will suggest to get the edges in increasing order?

Comment: wouldnt it be better if u use vector representation of graph?

Comment: @TanujYadav Yes, it would be better but only for this case. I want to keep same structure for solving graph problems.

Comment: Not only for this case, vectors are best  for solving graph problems

Comment: For djikstra?  Use std::priority_queue. Just give it std::greater<T> as the comparison function (default is std::less) if you need to invert the order.

Comment: @TanujYadav Oh ok. I did not try that. I shall try vectors next time for sure. Thanks for the suggestion. Btw, what would you do in this situation?

Comment: do u just need the weights in sorted order or their nodes also?

Comment: @TanujYadav Edges based on their weights.

Comment: It kind of depends when you want them sorted, and why.  If you don't take that into account and select the data structure you need, then you may end up with O(n^2) performance, or worse from sorting over and over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well. What I implemented is something like this :

When I add an node in the linked list, add it in sorted way such that linked list remains sorted by weight. So, final graph depiction would look like as :

```
[0,  1,  2,  3]
 |   |   |   |
 6   10  4   5
 |   |   |   |
[2] [0] [3] [0]
 |   |   |   |
10   15  6   6
 |   |   |   |
[1] [3] [0] [2]
 |   |   |   |
 |   |   |   15
    NULL     |
            [1]
             |
             |
            NULL
```

And then write an iterator which go over all the linked lists and put values into the vector. vector template would be :

```
// First int is weight, second is source, third is destination of the node.
std::vector < std::pair <int, std::pair<int, int> > >::iterator it = vv.begin();
```

:) Work with vectors in case you need to.

Answer (score 0):

If additional space is not a problem, I'd recommend to just create an `Edge` class with an appropriate `operator<`, but the edges into a standard container (I'd use `std::vector`) and sort it using `std::sort`. It's definitely a better idea than implementing your own sorting algorithm.

By the way, I don't see any reason to use the structure you're using now. If you want to store edges in a list, not in a vector, you can just use `std::list` (which has a `sort` member-function) instead of reimplementing it.

Comment: std::sort won't like std::list.  It expects a random access iterator

Comment: @KennyOstrom There's a `sort` member function in the `std::list` class (which is mentioned in my answer).